# Adding a Lambda function into Kinesis Firehose via Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-kinesis-firehose, terragrunt

I have a firehose delivery stream storing data in S3. However, I want to add a lambda function to the delivery stream to parse data before storage.

Do I need an IAM policy in addition to kinesis policies for this purpose?

Comment: Didn't you ask that already?

Comment: the other question is to create firehose stream and is not my question. I need to create a lambda function and attach to existing firehose.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I answered this, but maybe it was different question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `processing_configuration` to your `aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream` of `type = "Lambda"`. Doing this you will need to also add `RoleArn` to IAM role that your firehose will use to invoke the function. The role must contain the following IAM policy:

```
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:InvokeFunction",
                "lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration"
            ],
            "Resource": "<your-lambda-function-arn>"
        }
```